# Obstruction theory for hypersurfaces using T1 Lifting?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X \subset \mathbf P^n$ be a non-singular hypersurface of degree $d$.  Since $X$ is a regular embedding, it is known that the abstract deformations of $X$ are unobstructed.  This is done by identifying the obstruction class as an element in $H^1(X, N_{X/\mathbf P^n}) = H^1(X, \mathcal O_X(d)) = 0$ (see Sernesi *Deformation of Algebraic Schemes* 3.2.2).

Can the fact that deformations are unobstructed be seen using T1-lifting over $\mathbf C$? Precisely, given a deformation $\mathcal X \to S = \mathrm{Spec}~A$ over an Artin $\mathbf C$-algebra, $S' \subset S$ a closed subscheme and $\mathcal X' = X \times_S S'$ the induced deformation, is it true that $H^1(T_{\mathcal X/S}) \to H^1(T_{\mathcal X'/S'})$ is surjective?  If not, is it true for large enough $d$?